# MySQL MATCH ITEMS by partial or similar DESCRIPTION

Tags: mysql, substring, matching

Hey guys I am trying to figure out how can I match certain products with similar yet not allways same names or key difference in name.

Here is the thing.

I have chosen a particular category of products, it is some car parts lets not get into that :).

So the guys in purchase will sometimes add a description 'this and that L' or 'this and that R'
which means that the part is LEFT or RIGHT, they sell separately or you can buy them in pair but in order to do so I would need to match all the exact LEFTS with the RIGHTS. To make it more complicated, every person who works in purchase has their own unique style of writing, sometimes the L will be in the middle sometimes at the end, sometimes with a slash /L a lot going on, also the product_id should in most cases one after another lets say 10001 L and 10002, R but not in general, my final sintax should also be with a condition that I want to see if my stock from matching L  is different than stock from matching R, that way an option to buy in pair would allways be available.

here is an example of the table

[image]

So i am thinking GROUP BY brand, match by description somehow and display results on condition where stock from matching L <> stock from matching R.

Any ideas how to attack the description string are welcomed. I should point out that isolating just L or R from the string would not be wise cause one brand can have many matching pairs. Also I should assign like L or R for all items in all matching groups so I can calculate their difference I guess

Comment: Have you investigated full text indexing?

Comment: What version of MySQL or MariaDB do you use? I ask because regex string-substitution operations might help and they're only available in later versions. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: its the latest, I was thinking of that solution also, i managed to get a list of clean results, by naming more and more conditions as you can see listed oin the next post, but eventually in that particular solution I could get an item thats matched with another string length and is in + -2 id_number, I have to check if the items that werent in the range of +-1 are actually some kind of outliers or non acvtive atm, then I can use the range +-1 cause it sure seems thatz 99,9% of the matching pairs are logically created and listed one after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooray for dirty data. Your best course of action long-term is to add a column to your table called, for example, "hand", and get your purchasing agents to populate it correctly.  But you know that.

In the meantime I suggest you add a VIEW to your database so you can view that table as if it had the "hand" column.  In your view the definition of your extra column will include a big fat ugly CASE WHEH THEN statement to compute the value of "hand".

Why do it this way?  Your business rules for extracting the handedness from the product description are not well defined, and you will have to mess around with this VIEW to get it to do the right thing for all your various cases.  If you define it as a VIEW you will easily be able to inspect the results to make sure they are correct.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW inventory_with_hand AS
SELECT *,
       CASE 
       WHEN description LIKE '%/LEFT%' THEN 'L'    /* /LEFT */
       WHEN description LIKE '%/RIGHT%' THEN 'R'   /* /RIGHT */
       WHEN description LIKE '%/L %' THEN 'L'      /* /L space */
       WHEN description LIKE '%/R %' THEN 'L'      /* /R space */
       WHEN RTRIM(description) LIKE '%L' THEN 'L'  /* L at end of string */
       WHEN RTRIM(description) LIKE '%R' THEN 'R'  /* R at end of string */
       WHEN description LIKE '% L %' THEN 'L'      /* space L space */
       WHEN description LIKE '% R %' THEN 'R'      /* space R space */
       ELSE '' END hand
  FROM inventory;
```

Once you have this view you can use it to eyeball your data to see if you're handling the L / R thing correctly.  Use a query like this and scroll through the results. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haKdYj2G8eb9rdMZCPvQk2/1)

```
  SELECT description, hand
    FROM inventory_with_hand
   ORDER BY hand<>'', description, hand;
```

You'll, hopefully, see a lot of correctly handled data and a bit of incorrectly handled data. You can add new cases to your WHEN THEN cascade in the view until you get the data handled correctly.

WHEN THEN is good for this application, because it has the same structure as if / else if / else if / else.  SQL processes your WHEN THEN clauses in the order you gave them. When one matches, the matching process stops.

Once you have the right L / R values, you can move on to your query that searches for matching pairs.  There are many ways to handle matching up the pairs with your dirty data. One that might work for you is this:

Look for `description` strings that differ from each other by only a few characters.  The [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the strings is good for this. There's a [MySQL stored function](https://gist.github.com/Kovah/df90d336478a47d869b9683766cff718) to compute it from Kevin Woblick on Github.

Here's a query to search for pairs by brand, by nearness of ID, by the existence of both L and R variants, and by Levenshtein distance.

```
SELECT l.description, 
       LEAST(r.stock, l.stock) pairstock, 
       l.stock lstock, 
       r.stock rstock
   FROM inventory_with_hand l
   JOIN inventory_with_hand r
           ON l.id <> r.id            /* L and R must have different ids */
          AND l.hand = 'L'            /* left */
          AND r.hand = 'R'            /* right */
          AND ABS (l.id - r.id) < 10  /* id values close enough */
          AND l.brand = r.brand      /* same brand */
          AND LEVENSHTEIN(l.description, r.description) <= 5
```

This isn't going to work perfectly, unfortunately. But it's worth a try.

I used `5` as the Levenshtein distance limit to account for the difference between `/LEFT` and `/RIGHT`. If you just have`/L` and `/R` you can use `1` instead, and your query will become more reliable.

Caution: The LEVENSHTEIN stored function is **very** slow. Try to narrow down its uses by matching other things first.  I narrowed down by id and brand.

Comment: Please see my edit for a few more ideas. I stand by my suggestion to make your business users clean up your data.

Comment: In the end I used a combination, hand to extract all L and R atributes from crazy descriptions         https://imgur.com/a/5x5vXdX       also I found out that if grouping by brand two pairs have fullfilled all conditions same so basically 4 items were paired by one brand, i just added another condition to check last 3 charactes in the string, one case being the same and the other one different, enough to separate the 4 items and pair them properly  https://imgur.com/a/vsjRt86

Comment: I tested the LEVENSHTEIN method, seems pretty neat also, however the result set differs by two pairs, I will double check my condititions, really informative and cool stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Once again thanks for the input Jones, while you were busy helping me out
I was trying some options with matching string_length with condition that ID is only two numbers higher or lower and diference between L.stock and R.stock for the matching pair different than zero, and stock must be higher than zero

I must say got some pretty good results

```
SELECT id, description, LENGTH(description), brand, stock FROM data a 
               WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT 1 FROM data b
               WHERE length(a.description) = length(b.description)
               AND a.id <> b.id
               AND b.id- a.id BETWEEN -2 AND 2
               AND a.stock - b.stock <> 0
               AND a.stock > 0
               AND b.stock > 0)
```

ORDER BY LENGTH(description) DESC

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The LEVENSTHEIN FUNCTION seems really interesting, I am trying to figure out all the variables for creating the function so I could optimize it rather than copy paste...

AT first glance all I can see is that the maximum lenght of string is set to 255 and that would be the highest number to choose when apllying it, then he declares some strings or substrings and their length, and then theres a whole bunch of J-s, i-s, c-s, whatever the hell taht is... seems important :) any way...

I set the ABS lower cause mmost of them are just +-1, sometimmes to, but even tough it seems logical to set the distance on 1 or 5 eg. R or RIGHT it juust wont do. I have to set it to at least 20 to get a complete list of pairs which satisy the necessary conditions.

I used that to try out production capabilities and its great 20 seconds to export a CSV with a complete list of items and import to ERP which are candidates for replenishment.

Later I started to preform checks even with those items not matching all conditions and again got some outliers.

[image]

here we have 4ids;  2Ls &  2Rs but 3 pairs cause conditions were met:
L.id <> R.id , they are in range, same brand ...

what I have notices is that the descrp string contains a numerical substring which is basically like manufacturer code or something like that nad I have created a DIGITS FUNCTION which returns all numbers from the string.

code for L is allways lower then code for R

in this case  we have
(lower IDs have Higher code, usually its proprotional)

[image]

my digits function will return all numbers from the string

so from this 'KRAJNIK VW VO-ES-8215 L T-4 90->'

i will get 8215490   its matching pair should be 8217490

I was thinking like isolating the only character by positions in those subtrings which are numbers  5 for L    and    7  for  R  and name that relationship as a condition only character thats diferrent and its on same position should be smaller for L than R, but thats also the case in the mispaired example.

maybe I shoud just hey If one L id is matched with to R.ids, go for the closer one
but 33214 is matched with 33213 and 33215, both have the same distance, and the rule go for the lower or higher doesnt apply for the whole set, sometimes L.id > R.id...

one thing is for certain allways, L.code < R.code
EDIT: This is not a certainty any more... I ve pulled older data from stock;
Its Texas all around

this is tricky business this is,
there are only 8 items alltogether as outliers, and not even interesting at this point I beliee company wise, but when you wanna do it right, heh....